# I am creating a login system in HTML...I have Used written a piece of code but It dosn't seem to workup..requesting to please answer

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code I had written
but the **If...Else** statement doesn't seem to work
(I have used MAPS here because I feel it easier{Please suggest if there's anything else that can be used to make it easier!})
I have attached my code for reference...
awaiting response
thanks in advance!!

```
<script>
function submit(){
 alert("hello");
 var username=document.getElementById("username");
 var password=document.getElementById("password");

var map = new Map();


map.set("Doctor_1","Doctor_Password.1");
map.set("Doctor_2","Doctor_Password.2");
map.set("Doctor_3","Doctor_Password.3");
map.set("Nurse_1","Nurse_Password.1");
map.set("Nurse_2","Nurse_Password.2");
map.set("Teaching_1","Teaching_Password.1");
map.set("Teaching_2","Teaching_Password.2");
map.set("Teaching_3","Teaching_Password.3");
map.set("Student_1","Student_Password.1");
map.set("Student_2","Student_Password.2");
map.set("Student_3","Student_Password.3");
map.set("Student_4","Student_Password.4");


if username in map {
  if password in map {
alert("password found");
}
else{
    alert("Wrong PASSWORD...");
}
}
else{
alert("Wrong USERNAME...");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should include your condition inside brackets `()`. In your code use `if (username in map){ }` and  `if (password in map){ }`

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for answering but when I run code with the Brackets (), it only alerts with the WRONG USERNAME even If it's correct...

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve in your question? We can solve this together if we have ample information to continue. Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Why are you using maps? I do not have enough knowledge on maps. Perhaps someone might be able to help if sufficient information is provided

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but your edit isn’t what I meant. I have updated my question so it’s clearer.

Comment: Are you inserting data into maps just when the data is submitted? Then you don't have a backend right? If I have understood you correctly, you are trying to verify whether user exists and also if the user has entered a correct password right **using the data hardcoded in the front end** right?

Comment: yes I don't have a backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping usernames to passwords. You should try something like this.

First, check if the `map` has `username`. If it does, then retrieve the `password` for that `username` using `map.get(username)` and compare it with the user-input. If it matches, you are good to go.

```js
function submit(){
  var username = document.getElementById("U").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("P").value;
  var map = new Map();
  map.set("Doctor_1","Doctor_Password.1");
  map.set("Doctor_2","Doctor_Password.2");
  map.set("Doctor_3","Doctor_Password.3");
  map.set("Nurse_1","Nurse_Password.1");
  map.set("alexa", "12345");
  map.set("Nurse_2","Nurse_Password.2");
  map.set("Teaching_1","Teaching_Password.1");
  map.set("Teaching_2","Teaching_Password.2");
  map.set("Teaching_3","Teaching_Password.3");
  map.set("Student_1","Student_Password.1");
  map.set("Student_2","Student_Password.2");
  map.set("Student_3","Student_Password.3");
  map.set("Student_4","Student_Password.4");
  
  if (map.has(username)) {
    if (map.get(username) === password) {
      alert("Welcome!");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong password!");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Sorry!");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="U">
<input type="text" placeholder="Password" id="P">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s my modified version. Your description of what “doesn’t seem to work” is not very specific, but I did notice you were missing a final brace.

If that wasn’t your issue, you can review my comments below. Note that in your code `username` and `password` are elements and not strings, so you’ll need to extract string values from them.

```js
function submit() {
    alert("hello")
    
    /*
    username and password are DOM elements
    */
    var username = document.getElementById("username")
    var password = document.getElementById("password")

    var accounts = {
        Doctor_1: 'Doctor_Password.1',
        Nurse_1: 'Nurse_Password.1'
        //etc
    }

    if username in accounts {
        if password in Object.values(accounts) {
            // it is strange to check against everyone's passwords though
            alert("password found")
        }
        else if (accounts[username] == password) {
            // I added this option
            alert('username and password match!')
        }
        else {
            alert("Wrong PASSWORD...")
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong USERNAME...")
    }
} //this last brace was missing
```